# c++ using-keyword in python

Tags: python, c++, using

In c++ you generally can do this:

```
using LCN = longNamespace::sub::subsub::LongClassName
```

so you don't have to write a long classname everytime. Is there a similar keyword or workaround in python for static classmethods.

```
class MyPythonClassWithLongName:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass

    def bar():
        # instead of
        MyPythonClassWithLongName.foo()
        # i want to write
        LCN.foo()
```

So that I can write `LCN.foo()` instead of `MyPythonClassWithLongName.foo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: classes in Python are just objects, so you can reassign them freely to a new name:

```
LCN = MyPythonClassWithLongName
LCN.foo()
```

Whether that’s recommended for readability is another matter.

Comment: Oh I love Python. I really do. “classes are objects” 

Comment: Well that would work if it's outside the class. I edited my question, I want to call LCN.foo() inside the class. See the new method `bar()`. Sorry I it should have been more detailed

Comment: @Cowboy_Patrick No problem, the solution still works in that situation.

Comment: I don't know how but it does :o Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Alongside what was suggested by the other answers you can also specify an alias during import:

```
from longName.evenLongerName import LongClassName as LCN

lcn = LCN()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind a new name for the same class.

```
LCN=MyPythonClassWithLongName
LCN.foo()
MyPythonClassWithLongName.foo()
```